# Center align table in form in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, cross-browser

I have a table and form on my page that I would like to be centered. I was able to center  it in IE by having blank table columns on the right and left side with widths of 50%, but this didn't produce the same results in Chrome or Firefox. I need the table to be centered. What I've got so far is:

```
 table {
       width:580px;
       margin-left: auto;
       margin-right: auto;
       }
 form {
      width:580px;
      margin:0 auto;
      }
```

Right now the table appears as left aligned, but I need it to be centered.

Additional info:

```
label {
    padding-right:10px;
    text-align:left;
    {
table   {
    width: 580px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }

.centerspacer {
    width:50%;
    }

td {
    padding:5px;
    }
.center {
    text-align:center;
    }

form    {
    width: 580px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }


</style>

</head>
<body>


<form action="https://test.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">


<table>

<tr>
<td class="centerspacer"></td>
<td><label  for="first_name">First Name</label></td>
<td><input  id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" />    </td>
<td class="centerspacer"></td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td class="centerspacer"> </td>
 <td><label  for="last_name">Last Name</label></td>
<td><input  id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" /></td>
<td class="centerspacer"> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="centerspacer"> </td>
<td><label  for="email">Email</label></td>
<td><input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" /></td>
<td class="centerspacer"> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="centerspacer"></td>
<td><label  for="phone">Phone</label></td>
<td><input  id="phone" maxlength="15" name="phone" size="20" type="text" /></td>
<td class="centerspacer"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="centerspacer"></td>
<td><label  for="company">Company</label></td>
<td><input  id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" size="20" type="text" /></td>
<td class="centerspacer"></td>
</tr>

<tr><td class="centerspacer"></td>
<td>
<label  for="city">City</label></td>
<td><input  id="city" maxlength="40" name="city" size="20" type="text" /></td>
<td class="centerspacer"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="centerspacer"></td>
<td><label  for="state">State/Province</label></td><td><input  id="state" maxlength="20"     name="state" size="20" type="text" /></td>
<td class="centerspacer"> </td>
</tr>
```

```
</form>
```

Comment: need markup to help you here... margin: 0 auto; should be right for the table though

Comment: Add your code to jsfiddle.  What you have looks like it should work fine.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MMmQy/ Here's the JSFiddle for what I have (I left out the non essential stuff that comes in after the form and table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your css is the problem:

```
label {
  padding-right:10px;
  text-align:left;
{  <-----------------  wrong direction ;-)
```

Comment: another hint, i wouldnt put your form into a table, i would use an unorderd list. tables should be used for displaying tabular data

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping the table in a centered div like this

HTML

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>bar</td>
        </tr>    
    </table>
</div>
<form>
    <label><input type="text"/>Label</label>
</form>
```

​
CSS

```
div {
    width: 580px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
table {
    background: red;
    width:580px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
form {
    background: blue;
    width:580px;
    margin:0 auto;
}​
```

see fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/DsbMT/1/

Comment: Tried a centered div as well with no luck

Answer (score -1):

EDITED:

Try this

```
table.inner {
float:right;width:50px
}
```

Source

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?588052-center-align-in-google-chrome-and-fireFox

Comment: have you read the question???

Comment: Yes. I dont understand the down vote.

Comment: I tried adding that div.centered class as well, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: he had already that margin: 0 auto stuff in his css what you posted...

Comment: Ahh right sorry my bad. Been a long day :)